# Calculating and displaying as label

Tags: ios, swift

I want to calculate Runs per Overs and display on a Run Rate Label.

As you can see in my code, the Run Rate will change as i'm using steppers for Runs and Overs.

The run rate need to be displayed up to 2 decimal points (eg. 4.50 or 10.74 etc.)

I want to create function but I don't know how to calculate.

How can I do this?

```
// RUNS

var runsInt = 0
var oversFloat: Float = 0.0
var runRate: Double = 0.0

@IBOutlet weak var runsLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var displayRunsLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var oversLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var oversRectangle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var displayOversLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var runRateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var displayRunRateLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func RunStepper(_ sender: UIStepper) {
let runsValue = Int(sender.value)
displayRunsLabel.text = String(runsValue)
}

// OVERS
 @IBAction func OversStepper(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    let value = Int(sender.value)
    let remainder = value % 10
    if remainder == 6 {
        sender.value = Double(value + 4)
    } else if remainder == 9 {
        sender.value = Double(value - 4)
    }
    displayOversLabel.text = String(format: "%.1f", sender.value / 10)   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_run_rate) for information on calculating run rate.

```
runRate = (total runs scored)/(total overs faced)
```

**Note:**  If `overs` is `47.5`, the stepper value will be `475.0` and
`oversInt` will be set to `475`.  When calculating `runRate`, `47.5`
actually represents `47 5/6` which we can calculate as
`Double(oversInt / 10) + Double(oversInt % 10) / 6`

Create a function called `calculateRunRate` and 
add property observers (`didSet`) to `runsInt` and `oversInt` to trigger the calculation of `runRate`.  Then anytime either of those values changes, `runRate` will be recalculated and the `displayRunRate` label will be updated.

```
// RUNS

var runsInt = 0 {
    didSet {
        calculateRunRate()
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var runsLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var displayRunsLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func RunStepper(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    runsInt = Int(sender.value)
    displayRunsLabel.text = String(runsInt)
}


// OVERS

var oversInt = 0 {
    didSet {
        calculateRunRate()
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var oversLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var oversRectangle: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var displayOversLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func OversStepper(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    var value = Int(sender.value)
    let remainder = value % 10
    if remainder == 6 {
        value += 4
    } else if remainder == 9 {
        value -= 4
    }
    sender.value = Double(value)
    oversInt = value

    displayOversLabel.text = String(format: "%.1f", sender.value / 10)
}


// RUN RATE

var runRate = 0.0
let maxOvers = 40.0

@IBOutlet weak var runRateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var displayRunRateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var displayRequiredRunRateLabel: UILabel!

func calculateRunRate() {
    var oversDouble = 0.0

    // Don't divide by zero
    if oversInt == 0 {
        // can this even happen?
        // set runRate to some value that makes sense
        runRate = 0.0
    } else {
        oversDouble = Double(oversInt / 10) + Double(oversInt % 10) / 6
        runRate = Double(runsInt) / oversDouble
    }
    displayRunRateLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", runRate)

    // required run rate

    let targetScore = Int(targetScoreLabel.text ?? "") ?? 0

    var requiredRunRate = 0.0

    if oversDouble < maxOvers {
        requiredRunRate = Double(targetScore - runsInt) / (maxOvers - oversDouble)
    }

    displayRequiredRunRateLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", requiredRunRate)
}
```

Comment: I just fixed a bug in the `OversStepper` which wasn't updating the `oversInt` after the `+/- 4` adjustment.

Comment: Thanks heaps. Worked a treat

Comment: hey @vacawama. How would I calculate my run rate as required? So basically, There would be a label called targetScore and that would be divided by how many overs were left. There is max 40.0 overs in a game. Eg. 200 divided by 40.0 Overs remaining = 5.0 Required Run Rate. As my over stepper counts up it should provide a new calculation every ball. 40.0 overs - overs already gone. How can I do this? Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I updated the answer to compute and display required run rate.  I believe the formula is `(runs needed to reach target score / overs remaining)` where `runs needed to reach target score` is `target score - runs scored` and `overs remaining` is `max overs - overs played`.  The code wasn't compiled, so you might need slight adjustments.